# How do I use this binary tree class?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have the code for the .h file and the .cpp file. I just do not know how to use it in the main. This is what was given, and I need to write the main.

.h file:

```
class binary_tree {
public:
    class node;
    binary_tree();
    void addRoot(const std::string &data);
    void addLeft(node *nd, const std::string &data);
    void addRight(node *nd, const std::string &data);

    node *getRoot();

    std::string get(node *node);
    bool isEmpty();

private:
    node *root;
};

struct binary_tree::node {
    node(const std::string &data);
    std::string data;
    node *left, *right;
};
```

This is the first time I am using a binary tree, and the the thing that confuses me the most is the class inside the class. I just need to know how I will go about adding strings into the tree.

Comment: made some changes, fixed some errors.

Comment: You need to write the main to do what? I'm also guessing you have to implement all of the functions declared in the class...

Comment: is this a homework assignment?

Comment: i have all the implementations of the .h file in the .cpp. Yes this is a H.W assignment. I need to know do i use addRoot to the object that i create for binary_tree or the sturct?

Comment: The struct binary_tree::node {..} portion is the class definition for the forward declaration you see in the binary_tree class.

Comment: I don't find this interface sufficiently self describing to know how to tell you to use the class. Either we need some documentation/comments or the see the implementation to give you some advice about how to use it.

Comment: ok I think i got it, I just need to know when I use `void addLeft(node *nd, const std::string &data);` what do i put in the node *nd position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some example usage:

```
int main()
{
    // construct the tree
    binary_tree tree;

    // add a root
    tree.addRoot("this is the root");

    // add children to the root
    tree.addRight(tree.getRoot(), "left child");
    tree.addRight(tree.getRoot(), "right child");

    // get the data with either of these:
    std::cout << tree.getRoot()->left->data;
    std::cout << tree.get(tree.getRoot()->left);
    return 0;
}
```